# AndroidManifest.xml:XX: error: attribute android:localeConfig not found

Tags: android, localization

I've got this error when trying to implement Per-App Language Preference in Android 13.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. Modify the AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
        ...
        android:localeConfig="@xml/locales_config">
```

2. Add a locales_config.xml in the res/xml/ directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<locale-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   ...
   <locale android:name="fr"/>
   <locale android:name="en"/>
</locale-config>
```

3. Add and specify the language locales and the compiled version in Gradle

```
android {
    ...
    compileSdk 33
    ...
    resConfigs "en", "fr"
    ...
}
```